# Regular expression not working as intended when I use an emoji at the beginning of a string

Tags: php, regex

My code is written in `PHP`. I am trying to store in my database subjects of the emails that I send, only after I remove the emojis that I include in the subject lines of those emails. I created this regular expression:

```
$cleansubject = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $subject);
```

It works when I have the emoji at the end of the string, such as:

[image]

But if the emoji I have it at the beginning of the string, it does not work, the entry is not even stored in my database:

[image]

Any issues that you can identify in my regular expression to achieve what I want?

**UPDATE 1:** Apparently the regular expression is just fine:

[image]

Comment: Use utf8mb4 in your database.

Comment: Give [this regex testing resource](https://regex101.com/) a try. It will show you what and how your expression evaluates against given strings.

Comment: @MarkusZeller That is exactly what I am trying to avoid to do. I am not interested in storing emojis in my database. The text is enough for me to remember which email it was that I sent. So I am trying to use a regular expression to remove the emoji before I store it to my database.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Great tool! Thank you. See my `UPDATE 1`. Apparently my regular expression is just fine. Weird issue. Maybe something else happened that had nothing to do with the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an encoding problem ([3v4l example](https://3v4l.org/X2srn)):

```php
echo utf8_encode('⌨️,,, Learning Online: Digital Marketing Course');
// Output: âŒ¨ï¸,ðŸ–¥,ðŸ–¨, Learning Online: Digital Marketing Course
```

When you try to match using your pattern this fails ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/4iTT8F/2)), but if you instead match any number of non-word characters without the global flag [like here](https://regex101.com/r/4iTT8F/3) you match the whole emoji.

And using `preg_match()` this becomes:

```php
$re = '/\W*/';
$str = 'â¨ï¸,ð¥,ð¨, Learning online: Digital Marketing Course';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
// Output: Learning online: Digital Marketing Course
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the ["u" modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to your regular expression to make it treat strings as UTF-8.

```
$cleansubject = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/u", "", $subject);
```

Or use a built-in function to remove the Unicode characters from your string, eg [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), [utf8_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), or [recode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.recode-string.php).

```
$cleansubject = trim(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $subject));
```